# VIM: delete range and paste it in current line

Tags: vim, copy, range, paste

In VIM, is there a command that allow me to delete a range and copy it where my cursor is? Or to copy it directly in a chosen line?

For instance:

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
line 5
line 6
line 7
line 8
```

I can:

```
:6,8d
```

and it will cut the line from 6 to 8. How do I managed to copy them just after line 1?

I tried:

```
:6,8dp
```

and:

```
:6,8d|p
```

without succeeding...

Thank you!

Comment: If I do that: my cursor is initially on line 2; I execute the commande :6,8d<Enter>, then the cursor is on line 6... :( But the p paste the 2 lines.

Comment: You can use `''` to jump back to the position before the latest jump, i.e. where you were before `:6,8d<cr>`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are looking for the move command. `:h move`

To move it to where your cursor is you can use:

```
:6,8m.
```

To move it to a chosen line you would use:

```
:6,8m1
```

Comment: Thanks! It's basically move, and not cut / paste... Windows habits... :D

Comment: `:6,8m.` is technically closer to what the OP is trying to do and you don't need the space between the command and its address.

Answer (score -1):

you can copy a line with `yy` or same lines with `<x>y -> 3y` if you want to copy same words use `<x>wy -> 3wy`

if you want to cut some lines use `<x>d -> 12d` and to cut words use `<x>wd -> 13wd`

and you past it with `P` about your courser and `p` under your courser.

Comment: Yep, I know those commands ^^ For my example the thing is I want, in one command, to delete line 6 -> 8 and paste them directly under line 1. And apparently that's not that obvious for me :(